# Permutation of lists, combining and not combining list position

Tags: python, list, permutation, variant, invariants

I found a good script for the permutation of lists, combining and not combining list position on a tutorial and modified.

Here is the script:

```
`your text`
list1 = [1]
list2 = [6, 7, 8]
list3 = [9, 10, 11]
list4 = [12]

print("The original lists are : " + str(list1) +
      " " + str(list2) +
      " " + str(list3) +
      " " + str(list4))

res = [[i, j, k, l] for i in list1
                for j in list2
                for k in list3
                for l in list4]

print("All possible permutations are:")
for perm in res:
    print(*perm)
```

Resulting in this:

```
1 6 9 12
1 6 10 12
1 6 11 12
1 7 9 12
1 7 10 12
1 7 11 12
1 8 9 12
1 8 10 12
1 8 11 12
```

My problem is I would also like to have the result permutated result of some list, like list 3 and list 4, adding this result to the previous one:

```
1 9 6 12
1 10 6 12
1 11 6 12
1 9 7 12
```

Etc...

Is this possible? I cant find a tutorial/solution to add this to the script.

I'm quite new on python programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. What you have now is the cartesian product of the lists, and you also want "some" permuations of those list? Which ones? In any case, you should probably check out [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Comment: Do you want something like this? `[x for p in itertools.permutations(lists) for x in itertools.product(*p)]` (here, `lists` is a list holding your 4 lists)

Comment: First of all thanks Tobias for answering.

My ultimate goal in this specific code is having elements in list 1 and 4 to change based on list, but stay in the first and fourth position of the final line result.
While the script also permute in second and third position all the elements of list 2 and list 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what result you want to achieve. But as I understand your question, you want to create the list `res` from the lists `list1`, `list2`, `list3` & `list4`, which should contain the following values:

```
1  6  9 12
1  6 10 12
1  6 11 12
1  7  9 12
1  7 10 12
1  7 11 12
1  8  9 12
1  8 10 12
1  8 11 12
1  9  6 12
1 10  6 12
1 11  6 12
1  9  7 12
1 10  7 12
1 11  7 12
1  9  8 12
1 10  8 12
1 11  8 12
```

If that's your goal, you can easily achieve it by extending your code as follows:

```
list1 = [1]
list2 = [6, 7, 8]
list3 = [9, 10, 11]
list4 = [12]

print("The original lists are : " + str(list1) +
      " " + str(list2) +
      " " + str(list3) +
      " " + str(list4))

res = [[i, j, k, l] for i in list1
                for j in list2
                for k in list3
                for l in list4]

res_2 = [[i, k, j, l] for i in list1
                for j in list2
                for k in list3
                for l in list4]

for perm in res_2:
    res.append(perm)

print("All possible permutations are:")
for perm in res:
    print(*perm)
```

**Update:**
To delete all lines that contain duplicates, you can extend the code as follows:

```
list1 = [1]
list2 = [6, 7, 8, 9]
list3 = [9, 10, 11]
list4 = [12]

print("\nThe original lists are : " + str(list1) +
      " " + str(list2) +
      " " + str(list3) +
      " " + str(list4))

res = [[i, j, k, l] for i in list1
                    for j in list2
                    for k in list3
                    for l in list4]

res_2 = [[i, k, j, l]   for i in list1
                        for j in list2
                        for k in list3
                        for l in list4]

for perm in res_2:
    res.append(perm)

print("\nAll possible permutations with duplicates in lines are:")
for perm in res:
    print(*perm)

delete_index = []
for i, line in enumerate(res):
    for j, element in enumerate(line):
        for k in range(j, len(res[0])):
            if j != k:
                if element == line[k]:
                    delete_index.append(i)

for i in sorted(delete_index, reverse=True):
    del res[i]        

print("All possible permutations are:")
for perm in res:
    print(*perm)
```

By executing the code you will get the following output:

```
The original lists are : [1] [6, 7, 8, 9] [9, 10, 11] [12]

All possible permutations with duplicates in lines are:
1 6 9 12
1 6 10 12
1 6 11 12
1 7 9 12
1 7 10 12
1 7 11 12
1 8 9 12
1 8 10 12
1 8 11 12
1 9 9 12
1 9 10 12
1 9 11 12
1 9 6 12
1 10 6 12
1 11 6 12
1 9 7 12
1 10 7 12
1 11 7 12
1 9 8 12
1 10 8 12
1 11 8 12
1 9 9 12
1 10 9 12
1 11 9 12

All possible permutations are:
1 6 9 12
1 6 10 12
1 6 11 12
1 7 9 12
1 7 10 12
1 7 11 12
1 8 9 12
1 8 10 12
1 8 11 12
1 9 10 12
1 9 11 12
1 9 6 12
1 10 6 12
1 11 6 12
1 9 7 12
1 10 7 12
1 11 7 12
1 9 8 12
1 10 8 12
1 11 8 12
1 10 9 12
1 11 9 12
```

As you can see, the two lines that contained the elements `1 9 9 12` were deleted from the list.

Comment: That's exactly it!

But here is the problem: sometimes the different lists (of words) are containing the same words.

Can I edit it with a code preventing the multiple word occurrences on the same lines to overload the results?

Comment: What should happen if a word (or a number) appears multiple times in a line? Do you want this line to then be deleted from the list, or do you want this line to be changed in some way?

Comment: Thanks for answering PD, just line deleted from the final result list.

Comment: Your update is perfect! Thanks alot, now I only have to modify it for twelve lists like that, I hope I can do it fine!
Grazie

Comment: You're welcome. If you need any further help, than I'll be happy to help you again. :)